# ファイルの特定行を別ファイルに切り出すコマンド

Tags: linux, unix

file1

```
hoge piyo
fuga piyo
hoge piyo
fuga piyo
```

file2

```
hogehoge piyopiyo
fuga piyopiyo
hogehoge piyopiyo
fuga piyopiyo
```

↓

file1

```
hoge piyo
hoge piyo
```

file2

```
hogehoge piyopiyo
hogehoge piyopiyo
```

file-huga

```
fuga piyo
fuga piyo
fuga piyopiyo
fuga piyopiyo
```

このように複数のファイルの行頭が`fuga`の行を削除し、またその行を別のファイルにまとめて出力するにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sedで:

```
$ sed -i -e '/^fuga/w file-huga' -e '//d' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

grep -v "^fuga" file1 > file1.new
grep "^fuga" file1 file2 > file-fuga

ファイル名は別途書き換えてください。